# Question about hardware is closed as off topic

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I asked a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1571746/how-big-is-a-tensor-core-compared-to-a-cuda-core) about computer hardware. I looked through the [section](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) about what is considered on topic on this site and I didn't see any problems with my question. However my question was closed as off topic, specifically, if I read it correctly, because my question is supposedly about a hardware recommendation.

What can I do to make it clear that I am not looking for a hardware recommendation and what do I need to do so my question gets reopened. And if my question is in fact off topic for this site, which site is better for my question?

Comment: As mentioned in the comments the only people who know are going to either be the designers, or those that have had reason to remove a die from its packaging and enough time to determine functional blocks. It borders on not being about the *use* of computer hardware and more on low-level electronic design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its rather broad, since there's no specific thing that determines the size of a core based on its design, and may vary according to role and generation.

While one might potentially disagree with the close reason, it is also a question that's probably impossible to answer authoritatively, and as an end user, rather than worry about the size of a specific core, how it does your task matters more.